# error: cast from 'char*' to 'unsigned int' loses precision

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am compiling a code, which gives me error in the following function :

```
inline char *align(char *var, DataType_e type)
{
    return (DataTypeSize[type] == 0) ? var :
        (char*) (((unsigned int)(var) + DataTypeSize[type]-1) /
                 DataTypeSize[type] * DataTypeSize[type]);
}
```

The following error comes in line with "(unsigned int)(var)"  :

```
error: cast from 'char*' to 'unsigned int' loses precision
```

If i change "unsigned int" to "unsigned long", the compilation works but i don't get the expected results while running my program. Any idea on how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: What are the expected results? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: What are your expected results? Can you detail that, please? Appearantly you're compiling in an environment that uses a `long` for pointer representation.

Comment: Are you sure this is even what you want to do? Depending on how you fill up the `DataType_e` object, it seems highly likely that the pointer that you get back will not be to valid memory.

Comment: Also, you should note that division and multiplication have the same level of priority and are executed from left to right, so I think your arithmetic is probably not doing what you expect it to do. You are dividing by `DataTypeSize[type]` and then multiplying by the exact same thing.

Comment: @Daniel: Dividing by a value and then multiplying by the same value has the result of rounding down to an exact multiple of that value. That's what the code is trying to do (after adding `size-1`, so that the overall result is to round *up* to the next multiple of `size`). And the result will be a valid pointer to `size` bytes as long there's at least `2*size-1` bytes of valid memory after the initial value.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: fair enough. I was just making sure.

Answer (score 6):

In C you should use `[u]intptr_t` if you need to convert a pointer to an integer type (but which you should avoid in the first place).

If they exist, these types are guaranteed to not lose information.

Answer (score 3):

The `uintptr_t` type is the same size as a pointer to POD.  Pointers to other data types, and pointers to member functions in particular, can be larger.

```
inline char *align(char *var, DataType_e type)
{
    size_t alignSize = DataTypeSize[type];

    if (1 >= alignSize) {
        return var;
    }

    uintptr_t varInt = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(var);
    varInt = alignSize * ((varInt + alignSize - 1) / alignSize);

    return reinterpret_cast<char *>(varInt);
}
```

Comment: `uintptr_t` is good for any `void*`, and hence good for a pointer to any object type, not just POD. Agreed about pointer-to-member-function.

Comment: @SteveJessop I thought pointers to objects with multiple inheritance could also be larger than `uintptr_t`.  I've never read the standard so I could be completely off base on this.

Comment: pointers are permitted to be any *size*, but even if it occupies more bytes of storage than `void*`, any pointer to an object type can be converted to `void*` and back and result in the same value (5.2.9/13). So it can't "really" be bigger even if some peculiar implementation pads it out with extra data. Similarly any `void*` can be converted to `uintptr_t` and back.

Answer (score 0):

When you're going to do math operations with pointers you should use pointer arithmetics instead of casting your pointer values to 'int' or 'long', calculate and cast back to pointer. This is prone for bad results, because the compiler can't respect alignment rules for the calculations.

I'm pretty sure that the 'unexpected' result of the function in your example has nothing to do with the cast at all. You should explain more about the calculations done with the `DataSize[type]` values and what you want to achieve with it.

Comment: Except you can't perform division or multiplication on pointers, and there are no alignment rules for `char*`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour You usually don't need to do this. You can perform division and multiplication op's on `size_t` values and add or substract these to 'anchor' pointers.

Comment: But in this case, I'm pretty sure you do need to. Unless you have a way to round an address to a given alignment without directly manipulating its value, in which case please update the answer to show us how.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Where in the OPs example is multiplication or division done with pointer values?? I can't tell what `DataSize[]` values really are, but I guess they aren't pointers. And as you mentioned there's no specific alignment for `char*`, so the correctness of the calculation result from the multiplication and division operations depends on the memory layout underlying the `var` parameter. But looking at the OPs example again, the result will be very likely the same pointer value as it was passed in.

Comment: The value of the pointer is converted to an integer type, then divided and multiplied by a `DataSize` value (presumably integer values), in order to align the pointer to a multiple of that value. Your suggestion to use pointer arithmetic instead of converting to an integer won't work, because pointer arithmetic doesn't include multiplication and division. Hence my comment "you can't perform division or multiplication on pointers". Sorry if I'm not making myself clear.

Comment: @MikeSeymour No, multiplication and division have higher preceedence than addition. So you'll have first the calculation of multiplication and division and added the result to the converted pointer value. So multiplication or divisions wouldn't be applied to the pointer value if no cast is there. It's just necessary to put the calculations with `DataType[]` in brackets.

Comment: The parentheses around the addition mean that that's done first, regardless of operator precedence. Without the cast, the result of the addition would be `char*`, which can't be used as a division operand. Without the parentheses, the division and multiplication will always give zero, and so the function would be useless. I'll repeat myself one last time: this calculation can't be done using pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Sorry, you're right. I've been overlooking the parenthesis :(